# Calling href from onclick method does not work

Tags: javascript, download, href

Hello i was wondering how can i invoke  an `a` click from a `button` `onclick` event:

I have made it work so far with these 2 methods :

```
<a class="button" type="application/octet-stream"  href="http://localhost:5300/File" download>Click here for dld</a>

<input type="button"  onclick="location.href='http://localhost:5300/File';" value="Download"/>
```

But i can not make it work with `js` ; i have tried like this:

```
 <button  onclick="Save('http://localhost:5300/File')">Download</button>

 function Save(url){
            var link=document.createElement('a');
            link.url=url;
            link.name="Download";
            link.type="application/octet-stream";
            document.body.append(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
            delete link;
        }
```

**P.S** I need to use the `<button></button>` and not the `input` !

Comment: It should be `link.href`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code creates a link, clicks it then deletes it. You can instead just run `window.location.href` as you did in the HTML example.

```js
onclick = "Save('http://localhost:5300/File')" > Download < /button>

function Save(url) {
  window.location.href = url;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Save('http://localhost:5300/File')">Download</button>
```

Or, if you stick to your method of creating a link, you should set `href` for the link, not `url`.

```js
function Save(url) {
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = url;
  link.name = "Download";
  link.type = "application/octet-stream";
  document.body.append(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="Save('http://localhost:5300/File')">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `button type='button'`

```js
function Save(url) {
  console.log(url)
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.url = url;
  link.name = "Download";
  link.type = "application/octet-stream";
  document.body.append(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
  delete link;
}
```

```html
<a class="button" type="application/octet-stream" href="http://localhost:5300/File" download>Click here for dld</a>



<button type='button' onclick="Save('http://localhost:5300/File')">Download</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually need to create an `a` element? If not, I would use `window.location.href`, which is similar to clicking on a link.

Example:

```
function Save(url){
    window.location.href = url;
}
```

The only issue with this might be if you're linking to an HTTP (non-secure) site from an HTTPS (secure) site.

Comment: I do not need to explicitly create an `a` element.I just need to preserve the current page and start downloading a file.That is an example i have looked on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const btn = document.querySelector('button');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    save('http://localhost:5300/File');
});

function save(url) {
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.name = "Download";
    link.type = "application/octet-stream";
    document.body.append(link);
    link.click();
    document.body.removeChild(link);
    delete link;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Download</button>
```